# How can I fix this Query - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a little problem with my query, here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `realizado` (
`cod` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`datedoc` date NOT NULL,
`bank` int(11) NOT NULL,
`bankValue` float NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`cod`));

INSERT INTO `realizado` (`cod`, `datedoc`, `bank`, `bankValue`) VALUES
(152, '2014-10-22', 22, 1000),
(153, '2014-10-22', 23, 2000),
(154, '2014-10-22', 24, 3000),
(200, '2014-10-23', 22, 950),
(201, '2014-10-25', 22, 100),
(202, '2014-10-25', 23, 2050),
(203, '2014-10-24', 22, 150),
(204, '2014-10-24', 24, 3800);
```

The problem is: I need to get the **bankValue** from a date and still group by **bank**, something like this:

```
SELECT bank, bankValue
FROM realizado
WHERE datedoc <= '2014/10/25'
GROUP BY bank
```

the closest I got is:

```
SELECT r.bank, (select bankValue from realizado r2 where max(r.cod) = r2.cod) as Value
FROM realizado as r
WHERE r.datedoc <= '2014/10/25'
GROUP BY r.bank
```

here's the SQL Fiddle if u like -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83e309/2

the result that I expect is ( **22** - 100 / **23** - 2050 / **24** - 3800 )

Comment: sorry about that, I searched for a week about it but I didn't found nothing like my problem, now looking that question "Retrieving the last record in each group" I realised that's it I should had searched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go! (Thanks for setting up the sqlFiddle with DDL and bootstrap data :)

#### Working sqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83e309/10

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    realizado a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  bank, MAX(datedoc) datedoc
            FROM    realizado
            GROUP   BY bank
        ) b ON a.bank = b.bank AND
                a.datedoc = b.datedoc
```

Comment: where is the condtion '2014/10/25' ?

Comment: The condition '2014/10/25' was given by OP just as an example. This SQL works for any date range.

Comment: Shiva, the datedoc is really required (just put a where condition in the select inside of the inner join and it'll work fine) Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want the latest value for the bank.  If so, you can do:

```
select r.*
from realizado r
where not exists (select 1 from realizao r2 where r2.bank = r.bank and r2.datedoc > r.datedoc);
```

Comment: the conditioin is not incorporated  '2014/10/25' ?